# Как я могу изменить значение глобальной переменной внутри функции def в python

Tags: python, функции, telebot, переменные

Я работаю с библиотекой telebot и столкнулся с проблемой.
Мне необходимо сделать проверку по ID чата и я хочу чтобы настроить ID можно было командой, у меня получился такой код:

```
import telebot
import pickle

@bot.message_handler(commands=['setid'])
def chat_id(message):
        outfile = open(id_filename, 'wb')

        Chat_ID = message.chat.id
        print('Chat ID: ', Chat_ID)

        pickle.dump(Chat_ID, outfile)
        outfile.close()
```

Глобальная переменная Chat_ID не обновляется в результате операции и я не могу понять в чём проблема. Как я могу обновить её на глобальном уровне?

Comment: Может, не надо? Глобальные переменные - один из худших паттернов.

Comment: Во-первых, она не глобальная. А во- вторых, см. предыдущий комментарий.

Comment: Она задаётся на глобальном уровне до, этот код должен был изменить её значение, но не изменил.

Answer (score 1):

Пример работы с глобальной переменной:

```py
g = "Hello"

def fun():
    global g # Указываем что g является глобальной а не локальной
    g = "world"

fun()
print(g) # world
```

Если не указать global

```py
g = "Hello"

def fun():
    g = "world" # g Локальная существует только в пределах fun()

fun()
print(g) # Hello
```

Ну и использование глобальных переменных не лучшая практика. Если не ошибаюсь глобальная Chat_ID будет работать пока есть 1 пользователь а на 2 будет путаница... хотя это лишь теория. Подумайте о варианте использования классов.

Comment: Бот будет работать в одном чате поэтому не думаю что это станет проблемой, спасибо!